# Error using Ninject with ASP.NET V4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I'm trying to learn about Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC4 using this guide:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412383/Dependency-Injection-in-asp-net-mvc4-and-webapi-us

However I am getting the following exception being thrown when I try and run the application:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition on Windows 7. Below is my global.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Cars.Domain.Abstract;
using Cars.Domain.Concrete;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Common;
using Ninject.Web.Mvc;

namespace Cars.WebUI
{
    public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
    {
        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            kernel.Bind<IModelRepository>().To<EFModelRepository>();
            return kernel;
        }

        protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            base.OnApplicationStarted();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install the Nuget package for **Ninject.MVC3**, it should create a file `NinjectWebCommon.cs` inside the `App_Start` folder of your MVC project.

Use that file to load your modules and configure your bindings. As far as I know, you don't need to use this *Global.asax* code anymore, so don't subclass the `NinjectHttpApplication` inside it.

Comment: Thank you, the guide I was using is for when you manually download the DLLs, Since I used NuGet it was so much easier than I thought it was!