# FileLoadException after installing Ninject.MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC with Adam Freeman's "Pro ASP.NET MVC 5" book. Unfortunately all projects using Ninject throw the same error

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Ninject.dll but was not >handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, >Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its >dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly >reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This is exactly the same problem which was discussed in this thread,

[Issues after installing ninject mvc 3 in mvc 5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374406/issues-after-installing-ninject-mvc-3-in-mvc-5-project)

but the offered solutions don't work for me.

I have tried target platforms 4.5 and 4.5.1, Ninject MVC3 and MVC5. I have also inserted this snippet

```
<runtime>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```

in the `Web.config` file, without any effect.

Problem must be in the Ninject MVC3 and MVC5 packages. Whenever these packages are installed, any call to `Ninject.StandardKernel()` throws the exception, regardless if made from the `Global.asax`or the new `NinjectWebCommon.cs` or from any other piece of code (of course, this should not matter for this kind of exception anyway, but in this thread [Error using Ninject with ASP.NET V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408733/error-using-ninject-with-asp-net-v4) it was suggested that the error might have something to do with using the `Global.asax` for connecting Ninject to the application).

I have run out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add to your Web.config (i.e. SportsStore.WebUI project):

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

It should work with this -> `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">`

Comment: Yes, taking a look in the MSDN library helps sometimes. `dependentAssembly` is a child of `assemblyBinding`. It runs now. Thanks.

Comment: I am also running through this book. On my machine at home, VS 2012 Ultimate has no problems like this. At work, running VS 2013 Pro, I had to implement this fix.